# Why are packets not moving forward?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I have a server with forwarding turned on. I placed an iptables LOG target in the PREROUTING, INPUT, and FORWARD chains of the mangle table. I can see the LOG messages from PREROUTING, but not INPUT or FORWARD. I have no iptables rules other than the logging. Why does the packet not get past the PREROUTING chain?

From [various](http://www.aptalaska.net/~jclive/IPTablesFlowChart.pdf) [netfilter](http://jengelh.medozas.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png) [charts](http://linux-ip.net/nf/nfk-traversal.png), it seems that the only thing that can stop it is the routing decision. I have checked that forwarding is turned on, I don't have any special routing policies setup, and I do have a route to the packet's destination. Reverse path filtering is disabled.

[One netfilter chart](http://danieldegraaf.afraid.org/info/iptables/packet_flow9.png) suggests the packet goes through QOS ingress at that point. I'm not too familiar with QOS, but I've not done anything special with tc. My qdiscs are pfifo_fast (the default), and there are no filters.

Additional details: This is an IPsec tunnel endpoint. The packets are coming in through IPsec, getting transformed successfully, and re-entering the networking stack. It is at this stage that I see the packet get stopped after PREROUTING before either INPUT or FORWARD.

Comment: Can you add some more details about the networking setup?  Have you already checked reverse path filtering isn't the problem?

Comment: I added extra details to the question. rp_filtering is disabled. If I enable it and turn on log_martians, they show up in the syslog. Disabling rp_filtering again stops them from being logged as such.

Comment: do you have any type of analysis took like wireshark to see where they are going and where they are not?

Comment: Wireshark actually provides less insight than iptables LOGs in this case. It sees the packet before netfilter; we already know it's getting past that point because it is passing through certain netfilter hooks.

Comment: What matches did you supply with the LOG target?  What are the tunnel end points.  Which routes are set?  What is the `ip l`, `ip r` and `ip a` output?

Comment: Can you share your ipfilter ruleset?